# GraphQL Query to return non-iterable

Tags: python, graphql, strawberry-graphql

I'm using `strawberry-graphql` in python, and have a query that returns a list of `User`

```
@strawberry.type
class User:
    email: str
    name: str

def get_user():
    items = get_from_database()
    return items

@strawberry.type
class Query:
    all_user: List[User] = strawberry.field(resolver=get_user)

schema = strawberry.Schema(Query)
```

It works fine, but I want some additional attributes like `total_item`:

```
def get_user():
    items = get_from_database()
    return {
        'items': items
        'total_item': len(items)
    }
```

In above code, Strawberry converts the dict to a string, so It didn't work. I tried to create schemas:

```
@strawberry.type
class User:
    email: str
    name: str

@strawberry.type
class GetUserResult:
    items: List[User]
    item_count: int

def get_user():
    items = get_from_database()
    return GetUserResult(
        items = items
        item_count = len(items)
    )
```

But it says a query must return an iterable (`Expected Iterable, but did not find one for field 'Query.allUser'.`).

Is there any way around?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the fixed example:

```py
from typing import List
import strawberry

@strawberry.type
class User:
    email: str
    name: str

def get_user():
    items = [User(email="email", name="Pat")]
    return GetUserResult(
        items=items,
        item_count=len(items)
    )

@strawberry.type
class User:
    email: str
    name: str

@strawberry.type
class GetUserResult:
    items: List[User]
    item_count: int

@strawberry.type
class Query:
    all_user: GetUserResult = strawberry.field(resolver=get_user)

schema = strawberry.Schema(Query)
```

you can [test here too](https://la4de.github.io/strawberry-playground/#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).

The issue was that in the second snippet you defined:

```
def get_user():
    items = get_from_database()
    return GetUserResult(
        items = items
        item_count = len(items)
    )
```

but the query was still expecting a List of users

```
@strawberry.type
class Query:
    all_user: List[User] = strawberry.field(resolver=get_user)
```